# Building Ember + Grunt into an Express + Node project

Tags: node.js, ember.js, express, gruntjs

I just joined a team that has an Express + Node + MongoDB project with little to no front end framework.  I'm looking to build Grunt and Ember into the project.  I've never done this before, usually I start from scratch with some kind of stack (whether it is Yeoman or MEAN).

Are there any good tutorials for building Grunt and Ember into an existing project/things I should watch out for?  This question is probably too broad (plus it doesn't really have a correct answer...) but I thought I'd shoot it out here and close it in 10 minutes or so if that is the case.

Comment: You may want to look into ember app kit. Here is a post on rolling out your own. http://toranbillups.com/blog/archive/2014/04/06/Building-your-own-ember-app-kit-lite/ That said, the community is mainly working on ember-cli to handle project structure/building/asset handling etc. http://www.ember-cli.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's very little interlope between your ember and node apps. All you really need from express is to statically serve your index.html and the resources.

The way I handled it was:

- Create your ember app in a separate directory from your express.js app (so you don't mix up codebases)
- Directory structure:

  ```
  project
  |- backend
  |  |- ... your node app
  |- frontend
  |  |- [package.json]
  |  |- [Gruntfile.js]
  |  |- public
  |  |  |- js
  |  |  |- styles
  |  |  |- images
  |  |  |- [index.html]
  |  |- dev
  |  |  |- vendor
  |  |  |- controllers
  |  |  |- styles
  |  |  |- templates
  |  |  |- ... (other Ember folders)
  |  |  |- [app.js]
  |  |  |- [vendor.js]
  ```
- Your `Gruntfile.js` tasks should take their sources from `dev` and compile them into `public`. Must use modules IMO:

  - `grunt-neuter` to combine your js sources (recommended outputs: `public/js/vendor.js` and `public/js/app.js`)
  - `grunt-ember-templates` to compile your handlebar templates into functions, so you don't have to drag the entire handlebars.js to the client (recommended output: `public/js/templates.js`
- All the sources you will work on should go to the `dev` folder. This includes:

  - Handlebars templates (eg. `dev/templates`)
  - Less or sass styles (`dev/styles`)
  - Vendor libraries (`dev/vendor/...`)
  - Ember controllers, views, etc.
- If you're using neuter, put all the includes inside `dev/app.js` file, in the order you want. You can initialize your main ember app at the end. I like to separate vendor libraries into their own `dev/vendor.js` file. These will be compiled into their `public/js/...` counterparts.
- Your index.html should load all the compiled scripts and styles from the `public` folder. If you set up your project like described here, it should end up loading 3 javascripts and 1 css.
- Finally, add a static handler to your express.js app and have it serve folder `../frontend/public`. Depending on the config, you might need a separate index.html handler for `/` route.

This is the pattern I developed before ember-cli became popular. So far, I'm pretty pleased with the results. But you might want to check out ember-cli, just in case they developed a better approach.